# View doesn't move up when keyboard is present iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am trying to use this code

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.origin.y);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25f];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y =frame.origin.y -204;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25f];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 204;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

To move view up when keyboard is present but this results like this:
[image]

becomes this:

[image]

Can't figure out why and if it has to do something with the navbar or constraints.

Comment: I will not mess the self.view, rather I will create a new view with all those textfields, and change its frame.

Comment: And move it up to cover the Navbar? Will try it out

Comment: My suggestion is to use tableView as it handles this behaviour effectively. YOu can use multiple cells or you can use one cell with  a view containing all these elemtns.

Comment: Try to put all your content in a scroll view, then constraint scroll view's bottom to bottom layout guide and when keyboard is shown you change that constant constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use this beautiful library named [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager). Just add it through pods/manually and let it do your work

Answer (score 0):

Kind of what Alexey Sobolevsky said did the trick. Basically i needed to put them in a scrollview and add a constraint from the scroll view to the object beneath, then put all the views containing textfields inside that scrollview instead. This made everything work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First add the scroll view. 
Then write the following code.

```
//When return key press then bring the view back
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
   self.scrlView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    return YES;
}

//When the text field begin editing then moves the view up
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.scrlView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 30);
}

//When ext field end editing then bring the view back
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

     self.scrlView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind information.Please click the up arrow if it will help to you.